# Как объединить две транзакции для разных схем в одну?

Tags: jpa, oracle, persistance, hibernate, java

Есть примерно такой код:

```
ATransaction.commit();
BTransaction.commit();
```

Обе транзакции работают с разными схемами (т.е. persistence-unit у них разный). Нужно объединить обе транзакции в одну. Чтобы если какая-то одна транзакция не прошла то отменить обе. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала: после `commit` уже ничего отменить нельзя.

В вашем случае, думаю, следует контролировать одну транзакцию (как это сделать конкретно в связке #java + #oracle, не знаю) и только в случае успеха, выполнять вторую. И когда обе не обернулись исключением (exception), сохранять результат (commit).